# Not so simple RegExp (for me)

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Try to get some data from such text file

```
14.12. 02:00    
Клемсон  // 1
Алабама  // 2
50 : 51  // 3 and 4
14.12. 01:30    
Хьюстон  // 1
ЛСЮ  // 2
105 : 98  //3 and 4
(84 : 84)
```

Where 1,2,3,4 data that I need

```
1 : Клемсон  
2 : Алабама  
3 : 50 
4 : 51
```

Problem, that some data has this

```
105 : 98  //3 and 4
(84 : 84)
```

And I don't need numbers in brackets, just numbers that above.

I don't match know about regexp but I try to do this https://regex101.com/r/wW0nZ7/3 , if someone can help me It will be great!

Thanks :)

CODE:

```
var regex = correct regex;
match = regex.exec(matches);

while (match != null) {
    play = {
        game:game,
        teamf:match[number],
        teamfscore: parseInt(match[number]),
        teams: match[number],
        teamsscore: parseInt(match[number])
    }
    //dosmth
    match = regex.exec(matches);
}
```

EDIT:
I forgot to say that there are here such data

```
14.12. 05:00    
Нью-Мексико Стэйт
Вайоминг
59 : 62 
14.12. 04:00    
Аризона
Миссури
88 : 52 
14.12. 04:00    
Гранд-Каньон
Небраска О.
104 : 108
(94 : 94)   
14.12. 04:00    
ЮАБ
Сиэттл У
79 : 73 
14.12. 03:00    
Нортвестерн
Чикаго Стэйт
77 : 35
```

Comment: The difference between `105 : 98  //3 and 4` and `50 : 51  // 3 and 4` is not evident: why should the former be excluded?

Comment: As I said i'm not similar with regexp, and it terrifies me :(

Comment: It terrifies you because you should formulate what you are doing first. After you know the requirements, you can think of a solution.

Comment: @stribizhev thank you for advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the following a try:

```
(^[^\d\n]+$)\n(^[^\d\n]+$)\n^(\d+)\s+:\s+(\d+)\s*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/wW0nZ7/4

**EDIT:** Reflects updated question

Comment: Updated post, thanks!